# How to toggle a class using jsViews

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

Say I have an element in my template like the following:

```
<div class="c1 c2 c3"></div>
```

It has several classes applied to it, but at design time I won't know exactly what classes they are.

If the model used for data binding/linking has a property called `x` that is true, then I would like to add an additional class to the `<div>`, let's call it `c4`, otherwise I would want to remove `c4` and keep the existing classes intact.

How can this be done using jsViews?

Answer (score 4):

There are some new samples that cover CSS and class binding - and which show some new built-in support for toggling a class. So it should be a lot easier now...

In fact there is a [tutorial sequence on data-linking](http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link), which includes [this page](http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link/class) on data-linking class, and [this one](http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link/toggle) specifically on toggling class.

In your case, you would write:

```
<div class="c1 c2 c3" data-link="class{merge:x toggle='c4'}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in a template:

```
<div class="c1 c2 c3{^{if Properties.x}} c4{{/if}}"></div>
```

You could also do use a function to return the class value:

```
<div data-link="class{:~getClass(#data)}"></div>
```

Register the helper function like below

```
$.views.helpers({
    getClass: function(data){ //very simple, but you can see how this could be made more powerful by using data properties to determine class
    var myClass = "c1 c2 c3";
    if (data.Properties.x === true){
    myClass+=" c4";
    }
    return myClass;
    }});
```

Comment: I think those are both good ideas. Do you know if there's a way in the helper function to get access to the div and use jQuery to add/remove the C4 class instead of replacing all the classes?

Comment: In fact you can't  use the first approach - putting {^{if...}} inside the class attribute value. See http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link/class for an explanation. 
As to getting access to the div, yes, it is this.linkCtx.elem from code within the helper. But see my answer below for a better approach.